# How to call a function from another class

Tags: swift, xlpagertabstrip

In my `rootviewcontroller` i have three tabs below the navigation menu and each tab represents a list of products , in navigation menu i have a cart icon with a number on it to show the number of icons in the cart.
each tab is a seprate `viewcontroller` and they all refrenced in `rootviewcontroller` like this  :

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let firstTab = FirstTabController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let seccondTab = SeccondTabController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let thirdTab = ThirdTabController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

    return [firstTab ,seccondTab ,thirdTab ]
}
```

I have created a function in `defaultviewcontroller` to reset the cart number in navigtion menu but i don't know how to fire this function from `firsttabController`

This is my function in `firsttabcontroller`

```
func AddToCart(sender:UIButton) {
    let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: self.view.frame, type: .circleStrokeSpin, color: .red, padding: 170)
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    let parameters : [String: Any] = [
        "productid": sender.tag ,
        "quantityid": 1
    ]

    ApiServiceCart.sharedInstance.addProductToCartCatalog(parameters: parameters) { (success) in
        activityIndicatorView.removeFromSuperview()
        if success == true {
            // here i want to fire DefaultController().setupNavigationMenu()
            self.displayMessage(Title: MessageTitle.Successfull.rawValue, Message: Message.AddToCart_Successfull.rawValue)
        }
        else {
            self.displayMessage(Title: MessageTitle.Error.rawValue, Message: Message.AddToCart_Error.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried protocol delegate but it didn't work

github.com/kavehnaseri/Protino/blob/master/Protino . 
the function i want to call from default controller is (setupNavBarButtonsWithCartOnLeft) wichi is in helper/extension+UIViewController

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling function from another ViewController in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135402/calling-function-from-another-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Your exact question title comes up with many duplicate questions on stack overflow.

Comment: Show more code in regards to your reset : defaultviewcontroller, perhaps you have it on github so I could have a look and contribute

Comment: @ADProgress, this is the link : https://github.com/kavehnaseri/Protino/blob/master/Protino . the function i want to call from default controller is (setupNavBarButtonsWithCartOnLeft) wichi is in helper/extension+UIViewController

Comment: Check my answer below I have added a call to that method in the viewDidLoad but you can add it wherever is needed as it is accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution ,I should have used `NotificationCenter`

So , i had a function called `setupBarButtonMenu` created in `UIViewController` extension and what i wanted to do was just to call it in the ParentViewController from ChildViewController .
i added an observer in ParentViewController like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.setupNavBarButtonsWithCartOnLeft), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CartChanged"), object: nil)
}
```

and in another function from everywhere i can fire the funtion like this :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "CartChanged"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a trivial answer but sometimes the simplest ones are the best:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.myRed
    //THE LINE BELOW EXECUTES JUST FINE
    setupNavBarButtonsWithCartOnLeft()

    fetchProducts(pageSize: numberOfItemsPerSection, pageNumber: numberOfItemsPerSection / 9) // 9 - 1
    setupCollectionView()
}
```

as your function is an extension of UIViewController and UICollectionViewController inherits of it it is accessible in there already just try it when I ran your app it was called I have put a print statement to your function so that I could see when it was called. Hope this helped.